# Netbeans Android build.xml:483 error

Tags: android, netbeans, build

I'm new to Android development. While setting up my development environment with NetBeans, I came across this error when building the application-
The SDK build tools revision (10.0.0) is too low for project 'XXXXX'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
I don't know where is this error coming from. I haven't had any success till now. Please help guys.

Comment: Why NetBeans btw? Why not Android Studio?

Comment: Simply because it was already there in my PC and I didn't wanted to download Studio ;p

Comment: It'll a minute to setup your project once you download and install the SDK with Android Studio. This is a faster and easy development environment for Android. It'll take less hassle and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You must see your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` in your gradle. After that go to `File/Setting/System setting/android SDK/SDK tools` and check `Show package detail`.

you can see your usable Android SDK Build Tools versions.

Now you most change your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` with your usable SDK versions or update your SDK.

Here's a sample gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.4.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parsahealth.parsahealth"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.4.1'
}
```

Now you must Synchronize your project.

Comment: I checked the revision and it's 24.4.1 while NetBeans says it's 10.0.0

Comment: why you want work with NetBeans? Android Studio is a powerful UI for Android developing. if you can send me your gradle, i check it